# Different styles for multiple layouts in vuejs applications

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

I have two completely different layouts in my project - they are both two separate parent routes, with many nested components inside. I would like to use separate global styles for them. The problem is when I import the style in one of them, the other is affected as well:

```
<style type="scss">
  @import "sass/first.scss";
</style>
```

Because the import is global and it affects classes from other layout. The solution would be scoped styles:

```
<style type="scss" scoped>
  @import "sass/first.scss";
</style>
```

But then it doesn't affect all the children, only their parent elements, so it doesn't work as expected as well. Is there a way to use separate global styles like this in `vue.js` applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "deep selector" to target the child components within your scoped parent styles.

For example,

```
.parent-container >>> .child-element {
    background: red;
}
```

Some documentation here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles

Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly - I use sass and I have too many styles already to change all of them.